# Having trouble w/ returning and passing values; "counting"

Tags: java, parameters, return, return-value, jgrasp

Our task was to create a guessing game, where the computer would generate a number and the user was prompted to guess. We were to create a method to play only one game, and then create a while loop in the main to make the game playable again. In the end, we need to show statistics. I'm having trouble with showing the "best game." That is a game where the amount of guesses is the least.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {

   public static final int MAX = 100;

   // This is the main. Here we can see a do/while loop
   // and a few variables that were created to compliment it. 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      intro();
      String s = "";
      int totalGames = 0;
      int totalGuess = 0;
      do {
         totalGuess = game(console);
         System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
         s = console.next();
         totalGames++;
      } while (s.equals("y") || s.equals("Y") || s.equals("Yes") || 
        s.equals("yes") || s.equals("Yes"));
      totalGuess = totalGuess;
      statistics(totalGames, totalGuess);


   }

   // This method prints out the intro.
   public static void intro() {
      System.out.println("This program allows you to play a guessing 
      game.");
      System.out.println("I will think of a number between 1 and");
      System.out.println(MAX + " and will allow you to guess until");
      System.out.println("you get it.  For each guess, I will tell you");
      System.out.println("whether the right answer is higher or lower");
      System.out.println("than your guess.\n ");
   }

   // This method plays the game only once. It's later used in the main. 
   // Returns the 
   // number of guesses for one game.
   public static int game(Scanner console) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      int random = rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
      System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + MAX + " 
      ... (it's " + random + " )");
      System.out.print("Your guess? > ");
      int guess = console.nextInt();
      int count = 0;
      do {
         if ((random - guess) > 0) {
            System.out.println("It's higher.");
            System.out.print("Your guess? > ");
            guess = console.nextInt();
            count++;
         }
         else if ((random - guess) < 0) {
            System.out.println("It's lower.");
            System.out.print("Your guess? > ");
            guess = console.nextInt();
            count++;
         }
         else if (random == guess) {
            count++;
         }
      } while (random != guess);

      if (count == 1) {
         System.out.println("You got it right on the first guess!!");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("You got it right in " + count + " guesses.");
      }
      return count;
   }

   // This method prints out the statistics.
   public static void statistics(int x, int y) {
      System.out.println("total games = " + x);
      System.out.println("total guesses = " + (y));
      System.out.println("guesses/game = ");
      System.out.println("best game = ");
   }
}
```

Comment: What trouble are you facing?

Comment: Since you're calling `count++` in each if/else branch in the game method, could can pull it out to the top of the loop.

Comment: Looks like the solution by Sean (thanks Sean) solves the problem of "totalGuess." However, looking through the code now, I realize that my code for counting guesses in the game is a bit off too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, as you can see at the bottom "statistics" method there is one called "best game." What that is trying to do, is print the number of guesses from the game where it was the least. I have no idea how to do it, so if anyone could help out.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look when `totalGuess` is assigned:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Random rand = new Random();
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      intro();
      String s = "";
      int totalGames = 0;
      int totalGuess = 0;
      // ^ Initialized to zero
      do {
         totalGuess = game(console);
         // ^ Assigned (not added) to the return value from game.
         // Did you mean: totalGuess += game(console); ?
         System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
         s = console.next();
         totalGames++;
      } while (s.equals("y") || s.equals("Y") || s.equals("Yes") || 
        s.equals("yes") || s.equals("Yes"));
      totalGuess = totalGuess;
      // ^ Assigned to itself. No action.
      statistics(totalGames, totalGuess);
   }
```